# Docker: Invalid characters (%cd%) for local volume - Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

When trying to mount a local volume using `docker run` on Windows 10, Docker version 20.10.12, using

```
docker run -it -v -p 3000:3000 %cd%:/usr/src/app rails6
```

I get the error response:

> docker: Error response from daemon: create %cd%: "%cd%" includes
> invalid characters for a local volume name, only
> "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a
> host directory, use absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to run in PowerShell, using the delimited, automatic variable `${pwd}`.

```
docker run -it -v -p 3000:3000 ${pwd}:/usr/src/app rails6
```